# Unable to install pip on suse

Tags: python, virtual-machine, pip, suse

Pretty new to linux/suse and python so excuse me if I cause some simple questions.
I've search through stackoverflow and haven't gotten a result for my question.

I'm running on Windows with a Virtual machine using SUSE. I'm trying to install py.test, but to install it, it needs either pip or easy_install. I've heard pip is preferred over easy_install, so I tried installing that with get-pip.py.

I run it with

```
python get-pip.py
```

and it tells me it has been installed, this is what it ouputs

```
Collecting pip
Using cached pip-6.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting setuptools
Using cached setuptools-15.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: pip, setuptools
Successfully installed pip-6.1.1 setuptools-15.1
```

I tried running

```
pip install -U pytest
```

however the command pip has not been found. I also looked into python-pip package via openSUSE, though I'm not sure how to open a .ymp file through a VM.

Would I have to add a path for it to work? Pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: what does `which pip` output?

Comment: `which: no pip in (/opt/fsp/pub/autotools/bin:/home/orcm/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/bin/X11:/usr/games)` edited the output after i run get-pip

Comment: what about which python? Did it say where pip was installed?

Comment: `/usr/bin/python` for which python. as for where pip was installed, I believe it was installed in `/home/orcm/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip`

Comment: Ok. Well that is your problem. It is not in your path. How did it end up there?

Comment: oh alright. It automatically goes there when I install it. Though, I'm not familiar with paths in python, how would I add it to my path?

Comment: It has nothing to do with python it is your system path . Did you install another python in your home directory?

Comment: Oops. I thought it had something to do with `$PYTHONPATH`. I don't believe I have. If i had paths via my window will it also apply to my VM?

Comment: Not familiar with sure but try export PATH="$HOME/.local/lib:$PATH" and running pip again

Comment: It still says pip cannot be found. :-(

Comment: sorry made a mistake with the path but just try running `/home/orcm/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip freeze` first.

Comment: No luck, also tried adding a path to PYTHONPATH to see what happens but pip still cannot be found.

Comment: If that does not work then you don't have pip. Do you have sudo rights?

Comment: Should I try re-installing pip with sudo python get-pip.py then?. Alright, bumped into an error I assume: `Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f13709861d0>, 'Connection to pypi.python.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/pip/`

Comment: And also outputted. `Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pip (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for pip`

Comment: that happened with sudo python get-pip.py?

Comment: Were you definitely connected to the internet?

Comment: Yes I was connected. yeah that happened with sudo, without sudo it outputs that it's been installed (but pip can't be found)

Comment: can you install `python-pip` through suse? `zypper install python-devel python-pip`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like pip was unstalled by a regular user, so it was installed under the user's homedir, thus needs to be explicitly added to the path.

On openSUSE I'd suggest installing it using YaST (as root) and it'll end up in /usr/bin/pip, shareable by all users. Here's how it looks like on openSUSE 13.2:

```
$> which pip
/usr/bin/pip
$> rpm -qf /usr/bin/pip
python3-pip-1.5.6-2.1.3.noarch
```

Just search for pip in the software management tool.

Also many additional python packages/modules come prepackaged as openSUSE RPMs, better check the software management tool 1st.